# single viewmodel instance with multiple views

Tags: wpf

In my WPF app, I have two views to represent a single viewmodel. Both the DataContexts are set with the single instance of the viewmodel. But, the property change notification is not happening and the connection is lost between the views and viewmodel. The idea is, if the user changes data in one view should reflect the change in other view immediately. How do I attach a single viewmodel instance with multiple views?

```
public MainWindow() { 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    MembersViewModel userView = new MembersViewModel(); 
    MemberView.DataContext = userView; 
    MemberPreview.DataContext = userView; 
}
```

I have two views MemberView and MemberPreview and both are using the MembersViewModel. The MemberView is the detailed view and MemberPreview is kind of subset. When I change something in the MemberView (ex: MemberName), I want the change to reflect in the MemberPreview.

Comment: Please provide code, there is currently not enough to go on.

Comment: public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MembersViewModel userView = new MembersViewModel();
    MemberView.DataContext = userView;
    MemberPreview.DataContext = userView;
}

I have two views MemberView and MemberPreview and both are using the MembersViewModel. The MemberView is the detailed view and MemberPreview is kind of subset.
When I change something in the MemberView (Ex: MemberName), I want the change to reflect in the MemberPreview.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the binding modes to `TwoWay`, for example:

```
{Binding myData, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

I've found that explicitly setting the mode better guarantees that data will reach the ViewModel. The following simple example works.

Consider this ViewModel class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class VM
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _myData As String
    Public Property myData As String
        Get
            Return _myData
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _myData = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("myData"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        myData = "StartingData"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, a Window containing this XAML (omitting headers):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:VM x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding myData}" />
        <TextBox  Text="{Binding myData, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Second Window</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And this code:

```
Class MainWindow 
    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim n = New SecondWindow
        n.DataContext = Me.FindResource("ViewModel")
        n.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

A SecondWindow class is defined with this content:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding myData}"/>
</Grid>
```

The button instantiates the SecondWindow, sets the DataContext to the MainWindow's "ViewModel" resource, and that's all you need.

Comment: If I have only one view, the changes made in the MemberView are getting updated in the ViewModel. I am getting this issue, only when I introduced the MemberPreview view.

Comment: Do I need to set Mode=TwoWay for all the properties that I am binding from the ViewModel?

Comment: The default Mode is determined by the property itself, but generally editable properties (such as the text on a textbox) are TwoWay by default.

Comment: I found I had to add the `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` property to get it to work. As a best practice I tend to write XAML as explicitly as possible. The code is easier to read that way.